# Unable to install q4wine

Tags: wine

I just came bask to ask another question. I installed 
Ubuntu (again), but I'm having trouble installing q4wine. When I try to install, it gives me this:

```
q4wine: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.13-0ubuntu13 is to be installed
    Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.2-0ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is to be installed
    Depends: sqlite3 (>= 3.5.6) but 3.7.4-2ubuntu5 is to be installed
```

Help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you now have 11.10 installed reading you other posted question.

You have a dependencies conflict likely due to the installed version of Wine 1.3.

This is a know bug [#793777](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/q4wine/+bug/793777) and has not been resolved yet.